# My facebook like-share button has an unwanted underline

Tags: html, facebook-like

I have a facebook share-like button on my page. Suddenly it starts showing an unwanted underline. How to get rid of this.
My site is [captain-africa.be](https://captain-africa.be)

It was working properly. The the underline appeared. I created a new code from the facebook developpers page, to no avail

This I put after the  tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/nl_BE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v4.0&appId=608161489713020&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>
```

This I put where the buttons must be

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-width="" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" style="text-decoration:none;"></div>
```

[image: This is what the button looks like, I want to get rid of the underline]

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the element on Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: I did. This div unfolds in a complicated iframe of at least 50 lines of code, generated by facebook. Impossible to edit this

Comment: But what about `fb-like` class, what css does it have?

Comment: This is not my class, it is used by Facebook. I don't use that selector myself

Comment: But you can override it in your own stylesheet, just calling it after... or simply add an inline style... or even something like `!important`

Comment: I tried, even with !important. No avail..